# Who was the guy dressed in grey in "Transformers: Age of Extinction"?

Tags: character-identification, transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-age-of-extinction

I watched *Transformers: Age Of Extinction* a while ago and I came across this scene in the movie. I kept on rewinding the scene to try and make sense of it. Was this a mistake?

**Was the guy dressed in grey a civilian in the movie? What was his purpose?**

[image: two men hiding from gunfire behind a brick wall]

Comment: Can you offer a timestamp?

Comment: No. But this scene occurs when Optimus is fighting at the end. I think this just before Bumblebee comes in.

Comment: This scene occurs very fast though. It is during the very last battle.

Comment: I'm watching it now. Holy continuity errors, Batman. [2:31:07] First he's stood in front of a solid wall, then he runs to a wall with holes in it, then the guy in grey **magically appears**, then the wall is solid again, then has holes in it just in time for him to start shooting through the gaps. It's like the Continuity Editor took that day off.

Comment: @Valorum - I admit I almost slept through the last 3rd of that movie, but there were crazy continuity errors with a woman who was suddenly gone and all of a sudden back with them in the back seat of a car.  What a horrible movie.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock - I still can't get over the fact that one of the main characters had a special card that gave him permission to have sex with his [underage girlfriend](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/nikki-gloudeman/not-ok-michael-bay-transf_b_5549427.html).

Comment: “I watched Transformers: Age Of Extinction” — I think I’ve spotted the source of your problem.

Comment: There are no official sources or explanations for this, unfortunetly. One theory is that this is an SFX team member who set charges on the wall, and they exploded before he moved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the picture, I can see your "gray guy" is: A) holding some sot of gun, and B) has clothing that looks like some sort of uniform. He appears to be a soldier. I do not know his purpose; as he is probably just some insignificant man/soldier.

Comment: Although you're not wrong, pointing out the obvious isn't really helpful in this situation.

Comment: i don't see any gun! looks like his hands are covering his head to me!

Comment: Look at his waist. I thought that was a belt, but it has a barrel and a scope.

Comment: This is a very poor answer, if one at that. It might be useful to expand on this. Maybe show how you've gotten to this answer, what was your research? etc.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen somewhere (can't find the source) in a compilation of movie mistakes that it was a FX/fireworks technician that has been forgotten to be removed in final cut.

Comment: Without a source this seems more like a comment than an answer. Compilations of movie goofs are often very subjective and poorly referenced

Comment: ah, good point :)